# How to manage your SVN branch for a website?

Tags: svn, web-applications

We have a web app and we are 10 developers working on it.

This is our current branching strategy :

- A trunk branch connected to TeamCity for deploying in our Q&A server
- A release branch connected to TeamCity for deploying to our live server.

Where we want to take our change from Q&A to live we to a revision merge and we select our revisions.

And this is working most of the times. But in bigger project we have a lot of conflict and we don't really understand why.

I think the main problem behind these conflicts is the revision merging.

So I'd prefer a branch merging but I can't find something that is appropriate to our situation.
A Branch per development effort wouldn't resolve our problem :

- we code in the "FeatureXXX" branch then merge it to the trunk. Q&A does its job. But what happens when we want to merge Q&A to Live ? revision merging again (because we don't want to merge every Feature to the live branch only the XXX)!
- we code in the featureXXX branch then merge it to live but this remove the Q&A stage ...

Maybe there is a nice tool for merging revision without pain.

Env : c#.net , tortoisesvn, windows 7

Comment: The problem seems to be that over time your trunk and release branch have moved apart. So merging changes from one to the other is like trying to merge a feature from one product to a different product. You'd expect lots of conflicts. Can you re-architect your software so that features are distinct - like plugins perhaps?

Comment: this is a web application only used by us, so I don't see how a plugin architecture would be useful here. The only thing we can do I guess is to explode our main project into smaller projects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's something absolutely new for you, but:

**You can merge one source into different targets any amount of time**

I.e after

`svn merge ^/branches/FeatureA ; commit -m "Merged FeatureA intro trunk"` in Trunk-WC

and QA-games

`svn merge ^/branches/FeatureA ; commit -m "FeatureA pass QA-tests"` in ReleaseBranch-WC

is perfectly valid